# Add new shortcut to selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

How can i add new shortcut to Selenium IDE modifying its code?

For example, i want to assign to action `run test case` shortcut: `ctrl + p`, just like `save` action has `ctrl + s`

I could not find any js file responsible for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have asked ***make changes in the code***. I would suggest :

1. ***Clone*** the git repository [SeleniumHQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) on your local machine.
2. Search for the file which implements the *shortcuts on the IDE*.
3. Make changes and create a *`Pull Request`* on the project.
4. Wait for the admin to review it and *merge* the same.

> **Note** : This would put the usefulness of the idea and correctness of its implementation under regression which shall never be a cause of
>   worry if you want to develop on something.

***Edit*** : *On digging further I've got to know that selenium IDE uses a third party keyboard shortcuts script to provide us with the shortcuts.
The link to the specific file goes in here : [keyboardshortcuthandler.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/third_party/closure/goog/ui/keyboardshortcuthandler.js)*

Comment: Sure, i know i need to do this, but i can not find file which implements shortcuts for IDE, that's the thing.